# Select input takes value of previous select input when removing element from list of select inputs

Tags: javascript, html, svelte, svelte-3

I have created a list of select inputs in Svelte. The goal is to select a date and approve an item for that date. In case a new date is chosen, the item should be removed from the "current" list and appended to the "approved" list. See the code below.

Home.svelte:

```
 {#each $dummyStore.currentStates as currentState}
     <ListItem {currentState}/>
 {/each}
```

ListItem.svelte:

```
<script>
    import {dummyStore} from "../stores/dummyStore";

    export let currentState;
</script>

<div>
    <div class="columns">
        <div class="column">
            <p>
                {currentState.id}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <p>
                {currentState.name}
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <select id={currentState.id}
                    name={currentState.id}
                    on:change={e => dummyStore.addApprovedDate(currentState.id, e.target.value)}>
                 <option disabled selected value> -- select an option --</option>
                 {#each currentState.available_dates as date}
                     <option value={date}>{date}</option>
                 {/each}
             </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Whenever I select a date, that item will be removed from $dummyStore.currentStates and appended to another "approved" list. However, the next item in the list of select inputs will have the value of the previous item preselected. I first thought it was due to me not binding the value of the select element, but this doesn't seem to resolve my problems.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

In order to fix this, your code in Home.svelte should use a keyed each block. Currently, Svelte will not delete the previous select input from the DOM, but just change it's values. Hence, the old input value will be preselected in the "new" select element. To make sure Svelte destroys the old element, you should use a key for your element.

You can see the exact problem and resolution in this tutorial from the Svelte docs: https://svelte.dev/tutorial/keyed-each-blocks

To resolve your problems, change the code in Home.svelte to:

```
 {#each $dummyStore.currentStates as currentState (currentState.id)}
     <ListItem {currentState}/>
 {/each}
```

See this stackoverflow post with more elaborate explanation as well: [Svelte.js - Can't Properly Delete Item From List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59080722/svelte-js-cant-properly-delete-item-from-list)